# Getting soundcloud tracks with php

Tags: php, soundcloud

I've found [this](https://helgesverre.com/blog/fetch-info-from-soundcloud-api/) tutorial saying how to do it.

So I have username and got user ID. Now I doing as tutorial says.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
// build our API URL
$url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?"
 . "url=http://soundcloud.com/"
 . "name"
 . "&client_id=id";
 
// Grab the contents of the URL
$user_json = file_get_contents($url);
 
// Decode the JSON to a PHP Object
$user = json_decode($user_json);
 
// Print out the User ID
echo $user->id;
 /*userID 116386640*/
?>
```

And I receive an error.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/name&client_id=id): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized in getUserID.php on line 11
```

Of course I use my real user name and ID in url.
What's wrong? 
**UPDATE**
Also, I've tried second script (previously I've uploaded 1 track to my account).

```
<?php
 
$clientid = "YOUR CLIENT ID HERE"; // Your API Client ID
$userid = "5925312"; // ID of the user you are fetching the information for
 
$soundcloud_url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{$userid}/tracks.json?client_id={$clientid}";
 
$tracks_json = file_get_contents($soundcloud_url);
$tracks = json_decode($tracks_json);
 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tracks);
echo "</pre>"; 
 
?>
```

Again with my id's. Now I receive empty array.

**Update**
I get `{"errors":[{"error_message":"401 - Unauthorized"}]} message.` Should I use curl?

Comment: What happens when you go to that url in browser? For me `https://api.soundcloud.com/users/5925312/tracks.json?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID` shows some content - I'd start from here.

Comment: did u read my answer, sergey? ;-)

Comment: Actually I used JS api=) But your answer seems to me right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue with 401. go to dev -> apps and request new api credentials. i tried to accept the dev policies for the (old) app, but this did not work for me (linux / chrome canary).

here is a working snippet which fetches the tracks from a user, un-authed call:

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

$client = new Services_Soundcloud(
'client-id', 'client-secret');

$userid     = 1672444;

try {
  $response = json_decode($client->get('users/'.$userid.'/tracks'), true);
  var_dump($response);
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
  exit($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```